# Subtracting a value from an adjacent cell if cell value matches an ID matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

| ◢ | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | *ID* | *Score* |  | *ID* | *Penalty* |  | *ID* | *EXPECTED* |
| **2** | 1 | 30 |  | 1 | -4 |  | 1 | 22 |
| **3** | 2 | 46 |  | 1 | -2 |  | 2 | 36 |
| **4** | 3 | 41 |  | 1 | -1 |  | 3 | 41 |
| **5** | 4 | 20 |  | 1 | -1 |  | 4 | 20 |
| **6** | 5 | 53 |  | 2 | -10 |  | 5 | 52 |
| **7** | 6 | 5 |  | 5 | -1 |  | 6 | 5 |

[Table above, but in Excel (Shows cell headers/Better formatted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv52t.png)

The wording is kind of weird so hopefully the diagram makes it easier to understand. There are two seperate tables, "A:B" and "D:E". What I want to achieve is that if the ID value of column D matches the ID of column A, then column H should print out the value of B-E.

Ex.

```
D2 checks A:A for matching ID
D2 value same as A2 value, so H2=B2-E2
D3 checks A:A for matching ID
D3 value same as A2 value, so H2=oldH2-E3
...
Dn checks A:A for matching ID
Dn value same as Ap value, so Hp=Bp(if first encounter) or oldHp(if subsequent encounter) -En
(I think I wrote that correctly)
```

To note, column A will always include all numerical IDs and their scores but column D will only show IDs that had a penalty.

There's probably an ~~easy~~ way to do this but the one method I can think of is to just turn the data into a [2D matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWWOq.png) with ID going across the x, score being in row 2, and then penalties, if any, going on the rows below. That way, its just a simple SUM(r:r).

| ◢ | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | *ID* | *1* | *2* | *3* | *4* | *5* | *6* |
| **2** | *Score* | 30 | 46 | 41 | 20 | 53 | 5 |
| **3** | *Penalty 1* | -4 | -10 |  |  | -1 |  |
| **4** | *Penalty 2* | -2 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **5** | *.* | -1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **6** | *.* | -1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| **7** | *.* |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **8** | *Final* | 22 | 36 | 41 | 20 | 52 | 5 |

In the real-life case where I'll be using this, there will be upwards of 100-1000 IDs (not sequential, but still ascending in value) and thousands of penalties (not all IDs will have penalties, but all penalised IDs will have a corresponding existing ID). The matrix might work but it'd be pretty huge I'd imagine. (The columns might end up going past ZZ)

Comment: I've managed to look into the Subtotal outline feature but that still leaves me with the problem of needing to match the grand penalty with their respective IDs in the main table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
H2: =B2+SUMIF($D$2:$D$7,G2,$E$2:$E$7)
```

and fill down.

Change the `D` & `E` ranges as appropriate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it works. I don't know why I didn't think of SUMIF in the first place, but I think i was having problems by just using something like D:D rather than D$2:D$7

Comment: Managed to get it to work on a larger scale over multiple sheets and it managed to work flawlessly. Thanks again for the help.